# Amazon S3 - Access to Private Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, tableau-api

I have multiple images within a private S3 bucket and I would like an instance of Tableau to be able to access those images. Is there a URL or some way to access those images while still keeping the S3 bucket private?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Access Private Bucket through Tableau**

You can setup a IAM user with access permission to S3 and allow Tableau access.

Check the article on [Connect to your S3 data with the Amazon Athena connector in Tableau 10.3](https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2017/5/connect-your-s3-data-amazon-athena-connector-tableau-103-71105) for more details.

Note: You need to configure Amazon Athena for Querying the S3 content.

**Custom Generated S3 Urls to Access Private Bucket**

Yes. You can generate a Signed URL from your backend using AWS SDK. This can be done directly using S3 or through AWS CloudFront.

- Using [S3 Signed Urls](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property). e.g, Signed Url for GET Object.

  ```
  var params = {Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key'};
  var url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
  console.log('The URL is', url);
  ```
- Using [CloudFront Signed Urls](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/creating-amazon-cloudfront-signed-urls-in-node-js/). e.g, Signed Url for GET in CloudFront.

  ```
  var cfsign = require('aws-cloudfront-sign');

  var signingParams = {
    keypairId: process.env.PUBLIC_KEY,
    privateKeyString: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY,
    // Optional - this can be used as an alternative to privateKeyString
    privateKeyPath: '/path/to/private/key',
    expireTime: 1426625464599
  }

  // Generating a signed URL
  var signedUrl = cfsign.getSignedUrl(
   'http://example.cloudfront.net/path/to/s3/object', 
    signingParams
  );
  ```

  Note: Generating the Url needs to be done in your backend. You can setup a serverless solution for this by using AWS API Gateway and Lambda to provide an endpoint for authenticated users to access.

In addition you can also use AWS Cognito UserPools with Identity Pool to get direct access to S3 Private Content without the above steps. For this you need to use the Cognito UserPools or a federated identity as the identity provider which is connected with Cognito Identity Pools.

Comment: So if I’m looking to scale this to have the calls be dynamic parameter based do you have any recommendations for that?

Comment: Dynamic parameter in the sense? Is it for access control to different buckets for different users?

Comment: Dynamic parameter from Tableau. Example: user selects parameter and wants to see an image about a car. Wouldn’t I need to use Python or some other language to create that URL each time?

Comment: Yes. You need to do it from a backend code using the AWS SDKs.

Comment: There is another approach using Amazon Athena JDBC to access S3 from Tebleau. Check the link in updated answer

Comment: Thanks I was able to get it to work using boto3 within Python. I have heard about the Athena option but not sure I want to pay per query. Thanks for the help!